# use one domain to two different websites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need .htaccess file for a problem. I have two websites one is wordpress and one is in laravel i just want if i write simple domain example.com it will redirect to wordpress but if i write example.com/login it should redirect to laravel site. Can anyone help me Currently i am using .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /portfolio/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Is the path `example.com/portfolio/login`?

Comment: no sir simple example.com/login for laravel and for wordpress i need just example.com/anylink  please provide solution and recommendation

Comment: What is the file structure for your Laravel site?  What files does it have and what directories are they in?

Answer (score 0):

One thing can be done in an easy way.

- just create a new directory as "login" in your cPanel where the WordPress site has been hosted.
- Now upload your Laravel site to the "login" folder and make required changes in your Routes in file, so that the Laravel Login Page appear as default Route of the site.

Now you can browse your site directly to the WordPress and "YourSite.com/login" as Laravel Login page.